# O que é $$hasKey nos itens do array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Percebi que por algum motivo, uma propriedade chamada $$hasKey, foi adicionada nos itens do meu array. Cada item passa a ter essa propriedade com valores diferentes.

**Exemplo:**

```
[0: {$$hasKey: 'Object1', 
    uf: 'ES'},
 1: {$$hasKey: 'Object2',
    uf: 'SP'}
]
```

Neste exemplo é uma lista de sigla de estados brasileiros, o objeto que carrego do server não tem a propriedade `$$hasKey`, e meu array, vem sem essa propriedade até o meu `controller`.

Ao depurar não consegui encontrar o momento em que essa propriedade é adicionado aos itens do meu *array*.

Quero entender:

- O que é isso
- Para que serve
- Se tem como remover

Comment: Na minha concepcao:

A propriedade eh somente um jeito que o angular encontrou para poder identificar qual item eh qual, pois quando vc renderiza um array de informacoes na tela, o front end tem que ter alguma maneira de poder identificar qual realmente eh o elemento que esta renderizado e como ele difere dos outros semelhantes, esta ajuda tambem a syncronizar as informacoes ja renderizadas com alguma outra nova informacao a ser renderizada ou removida.

Deve existir uma maneira de vc poder customizar a KEY para alguma de sua preferencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> O que é isso?

A propriedade `$$HashKey` é criada internamente pelo AngularJS (mais explicitamente pela função interna [`$id()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)) quando a biblioteca precisa identificar unicamente os membros de uma coleção - como é o caso de uso de `ng-repeat`.

> Para que serve?

Para que o AngularJS consiga mapear individualmente os membros de coleções.

Quando você utiliza `ng-repeat='item in items'` sem especificar um `track by` internamente o ng-repeat irá aplicar `track by $id(item)`. Essa função calculará o *hash* em objetos, ou retornará o valor diretamente em primitivas.

> Tem como remover?

Sim. A função nativa `angular.toJson()` remove todas as propriedades internas - porém lembre-se que ela retorna uma *string*, e você precisa desserializá-la de volta para um objeto via `JSON.parse()`:

```
var objetoPuro = JSON.parse(angular.toJson(objetoComHashKey));
```